# Rewrite URL in jwilder/nginx-proxy Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm containerizing some websites. I would like to be able to migrate some rewrite rules to automatically append or remove `www` from the domain name in the request.

How/Where in the `jwilder/nginx-proxy` Docker container [nginx.tmpl](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl) or otherwise can I add some simple rewrite rules?

One rule for all proxied containers is okay, although it would be nice if rules could be specified per container.

Comment: Where you actually wrote these rewrite rules ? inside `location /` or inside a custom location ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein neither. I wrote them inside the vhost `server` block. Can they even legally be inside `location`? I think that would make things easier.

Comment: I get it! I thought you were using the location way which contain a rewrite inside it but you seems to be using the single line `rewrite`, am i right? then will post the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) docker image allows you to add a configuration per virtual host where you can add the rewrite rules as described in [here](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#per-virtual_host):

To add settings on a per-VIRTUAL_HOST basis, add your configuration file under `/etc/nginx/vhost.d`. The per-VIRTUAL_HOST file must be named exactly after the `VIRTUAL_HOST`.

In order to allow virtual hosts to be dynamically configured as backends are added and removed, it makes the most sense to mount an external directory as /etc/nginx/vhost.d as opposed to using derived images or mounting individual configuration files.

For example, if you have a virtual host named `www.app.example.com`, you could provide a custom rewrite configuration for that host as follows:

Under `/etc/nginx/vhost.d` create a file called `www.app.example.com` then add the following content:

```
return 301 $scheme://app.example.com$request_uri;
```

Then create a new nginx container and mount this directory to it. If you checked `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` you will notice that the virtual host has been modified to something like this:

```
server {
    server_name www.app.example.com;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/www.app.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://www.app.example.com;
    }
}
```

The include line contains the *return* statement that we wrote and of course you can add more rewrite rules to it

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Upvoted for now. Give me some time to check this out and I will get back to you!

Comment: This does exactly what I asked! Although I had hoped I could keep the configuration with the relevant container (such as `environment` for vhost names) and use `docker-gen` for adding the rewrite rules, but this answers my question! Accepted.

Comment: This does not actually work in production because [the config conflicts with letsencrypt-companion](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/issues/521). Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to recreate the container ? Restarting only wont be enough

Comment: Yes, `down -v` followed by `up -d`

Comment: So on the host there is no `return` but inside the container you still have it ?